# Summing a 4D matrix without for loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sum

I have a 4D matrix `A` of size `m × n × p × q`. Consider `B = A(:,:,1,1)` which is an `m × n` matrix. I want to sum all the elements of `B` to give a number. I want to do this for all such `B` matrices for all `A` so finally I will have a `p` by `q` matrix.

How can i do this without for loops?

As an example for a 3D matrix (for example `A` be a 3D matrix) I think this works,

```
sum(squeeze(sum(A,1)),1)
```

But I don't know how to do this for a 4D matrix...

Comment: performance-wise, it is better to sum over trailing dimension (i.e., third and forth) rather than the leading dimensions (i.e., first and second). So, if you can construct your matrix such that it is of shape `[p q m n]` and then sum over third and forth dimension - it would be faster.

Comment: Does it make much difference? The solution you have would work for a N-dimensional matrix for what I know. Except from that I would recommend shais proposal to sum trailing dimensions first if not your solutions makes more sense in terms of clarity. Reshape may also be faster I guess, but it have a slight loss in readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what's wrong with

```
[m n p q] = size( A );
squeeze( sum( reshape( A, [], p, q ), 1 ) )
```

Alternatively,

```
squeeze( sum( sum( A, 2 ), 1 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably fastest:

```
permute(sum(sum(A)), [3 4 1 2]);
```

**EDIT**: nope, Shai's first solution is faster :)

Comment: I suppose `permute` copies elements in memory because of the re-ordering of the data, while `reshape` only changes the header of `A` and not its internal representation in memory...

Comment: @Shai: maybe...personally I suspect the double call to `sum`, as your secnod solution has comparable performance to mine.

Comment: what do you mean by comparable performance? is about the speed of calculation?