# Fastest way of finding repeated values in different cell arrays of different size

Tags: matlab, cell-array

The problem is the following:

I have a cell array of the form  `indx{jj}` where each `jj` is an array of `1xNjj`, meaning they all have different size. In my case `max(jj)==3`, but lets consider a general case for the shake of it.

How would you find the value(s) repeated in all the jj i the fastest way?

I can guess how to do it with several for loops, but is there a "one (three?) liner"?

Simple example:

```
indx{1}=[ 1 3 5 7 9];
indx{2}=[ 2 3 4 1];
indx{3}=[ 1 2 5 3 3 5 4];


ans=[1 3];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost no-loop approach (almost because `cellfun` essentially uses loop(s) inside it, but it's effect here is minimal as we are using it to find just the number of elements in each cell) -

```
lens = cellfun(@numel,indx);

val_ind = bsxfun(@ge,lens,[1:max(lens)]');
vals = horzcat(indx{:});

mat1(max(lens),numel(lens))=0;
mat1(val_ind) = vals;

unqvals = unique(vals);
out = unqvals(all(any(bsxfun(@eq,mat1,permute(unqvals,[1 3 2]))),2));
```

Comment: and... Is it really faster?

Comment: +1 I like the approach. Just a quibble: `cellfun` is more or less a loop

Comment: @LuisMendo I would assume that to be of minimal work here, I guess :) I am just a bit worried about the bsxfun going to 3D.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Do you have any large data to perform benchmarks?

Comment: This approach looks promising from the point of view of speed. `intersect` doesn't seem to be fast

Comment: The thing is: Generally I dont have big data, but I need to use it A LOT of times. I am trying all your approaches, to see who wins!

Comment: @AnderBiguri May sound silly , but just to be sure, make sure to supress the output out here and for other solutions too. Made a slight edit to calculate `lens` and more changes at the end :)

Comment: @Divakar +1 from me too.  Also, not trying to bug, but was wondering if you happened to take a look at that script yet :).  No pressure... just wondering what your thoughts were so far!

Comment: Sorry to say, but your approach fails sometimes. Still trying to see why.
 ex: indx{1}=[47388 327602 18532 197333 327757 10453 95320 320 50873 189793 189795]'; indx{2}=[6044 150409 153084 327602 10453 73164 73167 73170 73171 95320 113865 189812 190421 197333 197334 327185]';indx{3}=[18379 47388 50816 197344 327757 10027 10035 10040 95327 197316 327602]';

Comment: @rayryeng Ah No I didn't! ;) Just being lazy about it I guess, but will soon , hopefully ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri let me try that out.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I had few issues copying and pasting that data, not sure what it was. So, this code expects each cell to have `1xNjj` data as pointed out in the question. So I had to modify the data accordingly, which you can try too - `indx{1}=[47388 327602 18532 197333 327757 10453 95320 320 50873 189793 189795];
indx{2} = [6044 150409 153084 327602 10453 73164 73167 73170 73171 95320 113865 189812 190421 197333 197334 327185]
indx{3}=[18379 47388 50816 197344 327757 10027 10035 10040 95327 197316 327602]`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Could you perform the benchmarks with this data again? Sorry to bother :)

Comment: I retried. And well, here you are kicking asses! but a couple of things needed to be changed for a looping case. 1: delete mat1. mat1=[] in thebegining, else sometimes it will have previous values. 2: in case lens is 0, add an if not to continue the code and avoid exteptions. but I guess thay are problem especific improvements. BTW, avg: 2.4e-4. Congrats!

Comment: @AnderBiguri That first one was a just a better way to pre-allocate  that I got from [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance), but yeah one can replace that with `= zeros(max(lens),numel(lens))` for a not so crazy pre-allocation. Agreed about the second point too! :) Was a good question BTW!

Comment: @Divakar - I've got a MATLAB question for you if you don't mind answering :).  This is part of that efficiency stuff I was talking to you about.  I've made some progress, but I'm experiencing a bottleneck.  Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use a `for` loop with `intersect`:

```
result = indx{1}; %// will be changed
for n = 2:numel(indx)
    result = intersect(result, indx{n});
end
```

Comment: Fantastic, great answer, as usual ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks! :-) I was trying to avoid the loop, but if a cell can have repeated elements I don't see how

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that @rayryeng's answer is faster! Check a comment there to see benchmark! But, just wow guys! thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Haha, good competition here, motivated by a good question

Comment: @LuisMendo - Don't worry Luis.  It turns out that Divakar's method is faster (as I suspected)... just Ander decided to play a trick on me and got my hopes up ;) hehe.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - This was a good question to ask.  A little competition doesn't hurt!

Comment: So in continuation with our multidimensional mathematical operations thing, I just came across this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508751/summing-a-4d-matrix-without-for-loops-in-matlab. Take a look!

Comment: @Divakar Again, `sum` seems to be faster when it works along lowest dimensions, right?

Comment: @LuisMendo Okay so shai commented in there this - `"performance-wise, it is better to sum over trailing dimension (i.e., third and forth) rather than the leading dimensions (i.e., first and second)."`. What do you think about it? I would think the point is to avoid "squeeze". In any case, we really need to perform some benchmarks to make it full-proof.

Comment: @Divakar Oh, I had only looked at the answers and their comments. But our (my?) conclusions the other day were that it's faster along leading dimensions, not along trailing dimensions, if I recall correctly. Yes, it could be caused by `squeeze`. This would make a good "canonical" Q&A  :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo If you are okay with keeping the summed output as the input multidimensional array size, I am guessing summing along the lower dims would be better, but in most cases we want it to be "squeezed" in and `squeeze` could slow things abit. Well all of these could really form some good canonical/reference stuff.

Comment: @LuisMendo - I've got a MATLAB question for you if you don't mind answering :). I'd like your input.  This is the first time I think I've asked a serious question where I'm stumped!  Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab

Comment: @rayryeng Looks like Divakar arrived first :-) I'll take a look anyway in case I can add a different view

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility that I could suggest, though Luis Mendo's answer is very good, is to take all of the vectors in your cell array and remove the duplicates. This can be done through [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), and specifying [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) as the function to operate on.  You'd have to set the `UniformOutput` flag to false as we are outputting a cell array at each index.  You also have to be careful in that each cell array is assumed to be all row vectors, or all column vectors.  You can't mix the way the arrays are shaped or this method won't work.

Once you do this, concatenate all of the vectors into a single array through [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html), then do a histogram through [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html).  You'd specify the edges to be all of the unique numbers in the single array created before.  Note that you'd have to make an additional call to `unique` on the output single array before proceeding.  Once you calculate the histogram, for any entries with a bin count equal to the total number of elements in your cell array (which is 3 in your case), then these are values that you see in all of your cells.  As such:

```
A = cell2mat(cellfun(@unique, indx, 'uni', 0));
edge_values = unique(A);
h = histc(A, edge_values);
result = edge_values(h == numel(indx));
```

With the unique call for each cell array, if a number appears in every single cell, then the total number of times you see this number should equal the total number of cells you have.

Comment: +1 I was going to type something similar as an edit to my answer

Comment: @LuisMendo - Thanks! :) I wanted to add a no `for` loop approach here as well, though Divakar has already done that... being the `bsxfun` advocate that he is!

Comment: Who could _not_ be a `bsxfun` advocate? :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I slightly changed my answer to make it more robust, as my previous answer assumed that indices started from `1`.  Also, the previous approach assumed that the values were integer.  The modified code now assumes that the numbers can be any number, and can start anywhere on the real set of numbers.

Comment: @rayryeng Nice to see the big guys compete for the best solution for the shake of SCIENCE! You are winning in speed! I run the code for Njj of around 30 each 1000 times.

Your average   =3.7e-4
Luis's average =5.6e-4