# Efficiently compute a 3D matrix of outer products - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have a matrix of elements like so:

```
A = reshape(1:25, 5, 5)

A =

 1     6    11    16    21
 2     7    12    17    22
 3     8    13    18    23
 4     9    14    19    24
 5    10    15    20    25
```

I would like to efficiently compute a 3D matrix of outer products, such that the i<sup>th</sup> slice of this output matrix is the outer product of the i<sup>th</sup> column of `A` with itself.  The outer product between two vectors `u` and `v` is simply `u*v.'` if `u` and `v` are both column vectors.

Therefore, each slice of this output matrix `B` should be structured such that:

```
B(:,:,1) = A(:,1) * A(:,1).';
B(:,:,2) = A(:,2) * A(:,2).';
        ...
        ...
B(:,:,5) = A(:,5) * A(:,5).';
```

My current method is the following.  I tried doing it this way using `arrayfun` and `cell2mat`:

```
cellmatr = arrayfun(@(x) A(:,x) * A(:,x).', 1:size(A,2), 'uni', 0);
out = reshape(cell2mat(cellmatr), size(A,1), size(A,1), size(A,2));
```

I simply loop over a linear index array between `1` and as many columns we have in `A`, and for each element in this array, I access the corresponding column and compute the outer product.  The output will thus give a 1D grid of cells, which I then convert back into a 2D matrix, then reshape into a 3D matrix to find the 3D matrix of outer products.

However, for large matrices, this is quite slow.  I've also tried replacing the matrix product with `kron` (i.e. `kron(A(:,x), A(:,x))`) inside my `arrayfun` call, but this is still quite slow for my purposes.

---

Does anyone know of an efficient way to compute this 3D matrix of outer products in this fashion?

Comment: have you looked into this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support

Comment: @natan - I haven't, but thanks for the link to FEX!

Comment: I wonder how efficient would this be vs Divakar's answer...

Comment: @natan - I'll download that library from FEX and I'll let you know.  Right now I'm looking for a purely MATLAB based solution.

Comment: @natan - It's not quite clear how I would use that library to compute the 3D outer product.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just a minor improvement over [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877959/2586922). It is a little faster because it replaces a 3D-array permute with a 2D-array permute:

```
B = bsxfun(@times, permute(A, [1 3 2]), permute(A, [3 1 2]));
```

Comment: Just a comment on timing - when I put this into my overall algorithm, the time it took to finish the algorithm with each solution was as follows with a `3125 x 3125` matrix: Divakar: 0.403 seconds, Amro: 0.304 seconds, Luis Mendo: 0.284 seconds.  I ran 100 trials of random data, and averaged out the times.

Comment: Just checked to make sure.  This will also compute the complex 'diagonal' (only matching indices) set of outer products between vectors in two separate matrices. Replacing the second `A` with `conj(B)` will compute `for k=1:n; C(:,:,k)=A(:,k)*B(:,k)'; end;`.

Answer (score 8):

To state the obvious, have you tried a simple for-loop:

```
[m,n] = size(A);
B = zeros(m,m,n);
for i=1:n
    B(:,:,i) = A(:,i) * A(:,i).';
end
```

You'll be surprised how competitively fast it is.

Comment: I didn't consider a `for` loop because I didn't think it would actually work.  I just ran some tests and this is actually slightly faster than `permute / bsxfun`.  Nicely done Amro.

Comment: +1 amro, sometimes the obvious needs also mentioning. I also prefer this over bsxfun, much more readable...

Comment: This is a great solution too! +1 BTW pre-allocating with `B(m,m,n) = 0;` could be considered too.

Comment: @natan - I agree.  I should have tried a `for` loop first lol.  Especially since the calculations inside the loop are simple.

Answer (score 3):

This -

```
B = permute(bsxfun(@times,A,permute(A,[3 2 1])),[1 3 2])
```

Comment: I always struggle with `permute`, so I had to break up each statement one at a time and see what is happening at each step.  I do understand what's happening now, and I wish I could have figured that out for myself!  Either way, I think it was a good question to ask :)

Comment: This seems to be a little faster, as it replaces a 3D-array permute by 2D-array permute: `B = bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(A,[3 1 2]));`

Comment: @LuisMendo - Your tweak in the solution actually beats out the `for` loop.