# How to profile a vector outer product in matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, vector, profiling

during my matlab profiling, i noticed one line of code that consumes much more time than i imagined. Any idea how to make it faster?

```
X = Y(ids_A, ids_A) - (Y(ids_A,k) * Y(k,ids_A))/Y(k,k);
```

X, and Y are symmetric matrices with the same size (dxd), k is an index of a single row/column in Y, ids_A is a vector of indices of all the other rows/columns( therefore Y(ids_A,k) is a column vector and Y(k,ids_A) is a row vector)

```
ids_A = setxor(1:d,k);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hm. Have you considered using the power of math? It looks like this should be part of some given mathematical formula. Do you have any details at hand? Is this some kind of decomposition?

Comment: I remember a similar concept called [householder transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) used for the QR decomposition..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perhaps replace the outer product multiplication with a call to [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
X = Y(ids_A, ids_A) - (bsxfun(@times, Y(ids_A,k), Y(k,ids_A))/Y(k,k));
```

So how does the above code work?  Let's take a look at the definition of the outer product when one vector is 4 elements and the other 3 elements:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)</sup>

As you can see, the outer product is created by element-wise products where the first vector `u` is replicated horizontally while the second vector `v` is replicated vertically.  You then find the element-wise products of each element to produce your result.  This is eloquently done with `bsxfun`:

```
bsxfun(@times, u, v.');
```

`u` would be a column vector and `v.'` would be a row vector.  `bsxfun` naturally replicates the data to follow the above pattern, and then we use `@times` to perform the element-wise products.

Comment: Very interesting. I ran some quick timing experiments and bsxfun is faster with any outer product larger than ~100 elements (100x100 output). I would not have expected that...

Comment: Odd. I thought I had seen quite a few answers, where `bsxfun(@times` was scratched in favor for matrix multiplication and not the other way round! Probably it was always the row times column `sum(bsxfun(@times` type...

Comment: @Raab70 That's rather odd! Does that mean that for small matrices, the `for` loop is better?  If you look at this question that I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab - I had two 3D matrices and I wanted to compute the outer products for each pair of matrix slices.  My input size was smaller than `100 x 100` per slice.  `bsxfun` was the winner in terms of timing.  My guess is that it all comes down to: (1) What version of MATLAB you have, (2) What inputs you are providing, (3) Processor and computer configuration.

Comment: @knedlsepp - You are correct, especially this question that I asked a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab - I had two 3D matrices, and I wanted to compute the outer products for each pair of matrix slices.  The approach that Luis Mendo provided with `bsxfun` ran the fastest on my machine.

Comment: @rayryeng: I just had a look: The `kron` source also uses `bsxfun`, so the guys at mathworks will also agree.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming your code to look something like this -

```
for k = 1:d
    ids_A = setxor(1:d,k);
    X = Y(ids_A, ids_A) - (Y(ids_A,k) * Y(k,ids_A))/Y(k,k);
end
```

With the given code snippet, it's safe to assume that you are somehow using `X` within that loop. You can calculate all the `X` matrices as a pre-calculation step before the start of such a loop and these calculations could be performed as a vectorized approach.

Regarding the code snippet itself, it can be seen that you are "escaping" one index at each iteration with `setxor`. Now, if you are going with a vectorized approach, you can perform all those mathematical operations in *one-go* and later on remove the elements that got incorporated in the vectorized approach, but weren't intended. This really is the essence of a **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based vectorized approach listed next -

```
%// Perform all matrix-multiplications in one go with bsxfun and permute
mults = bsxfun(@times,permute(Y,[1 3 2]),permute(Y,[3 2 1]));

%// Scale those with diagonal elements from Y and get X for every iteration
scaledvals = bsxfun(@rdivide,mults,permute(Y(1:d+1:end),[1 3 2]));
X_vectorized = bsxfun(@minus,Y,scaledvals);

%// Find row and column indices as linear indices to be removed from X_all
row_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[0:d-1]*d+1,[0:d-1]'*(d*d+1));
col_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[1:d]',[0:d-1]*(d*(d+1)));

%// Remove those "setxored" indices and then reshape to expected size
X_vectorized([row_idx col_idx])=[];
X_vectorized = reshape(X_vectorized,d-1,d-1,d);
```

### Benchmarking

**Benchmarking Code**

```
d = 50;          %// Datasize
Y = rand(d,d);    %// Create random input
num_iter = 100;   %// Number of iterations to be run for each approach

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('------------------------------ With original loopy approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    for k = 1:d
        ids_A = setxor(1:d,k);
        X = Y(ids_A, ids_A) - (Y(ids_A,k) * Y(k,ids_A))/Y(k,k);
    end
end
toc
clear X k ids_A

disp('------------------------------ With proposed vectorized approach')
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    mults = bsxfun(@times,permute(Y,[1 3 2]),permute(Y,[3 2 1]));
    scaledvals = bsxfun(@rdivide,mults,permute(Y(1:d+1:end),[1 3 2]));
    X_vectorized = bsxfun(@minus,Y,scaledvals);

    row_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[0:d-1]*d+1,[0:d-1]'*(d*d+1));
    col_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[1:d]',[0:d-1]*(d*(d+1)));

    X_vectorized([row_idx col_idx])=[];
    X_vectorized = reshape(X_vectorized,d-1,d-1,d);
end
toc
```

**Results**

**Case #1: `d = 50`**

```
------------------------------ With original loopy approach
Elapsed time is 0.849518 seconds.
------------------------------ With proposed vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 0.154395 seconds.
```

**Case #2: `d = 100`**

```
------------------------------ With original loopy approach
Elapsed time is 2.079886 seconds.
------------------------------ With proposed vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 2.285884 seconds.
```

**Case #1: `d = 200`**

```
------------------------------ With original loopy approach
Elapsed time is 7.592865 seconds.
------------------------------ With proposed vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 19.012421 seconds.
```

**Conclusions**

One can easily notice that the proposed vectorized approach might be a better choice when dealing with matrixes of sizes upto `100 x 100` beyond which
the *memory-hungry bsxfun* slows us down.