# Matrix Multiplication Issue - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

In an attempt to create my own covariance function in MatLab I need to perform matrix multiplication on a row to create a matrix.

Given a matrix D where

```
D = [-2.2769    0.8746
      0.6690   -0.4720
     -1.0030   -0.9188
      2.6111    0.5162]
```

Now for each row I need manufacture a matrix. For example the first row `R = [-2.2770, 0.8746]` I would want the matrix M to be returned where `M = [5.1847, -1.9915; -1.9915, 0.7649]`.

Below is what I have written so far. I am asking for some advice to explain how to use matrix multiplication on a rows to produce matrices?

```
% Find matrices using matrix multiplication
for i=1:size(D, 1)
    P1 = (D(i,:))
    P2 = transpose(P1)
    M = P1*P2
end
```

Comment: That code does not do any matrix multiplication....

Comment: @AnderBiguri You are absolutely correct - I uploaded the wrong code. I have edited the code to show what I was meant to put. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compute the outer product of each row with itself stored as individual slices in a 3D matrix.

Your code almost works. What you're doing instead is computing the **inner product** or the dot product of each row with itself. As such it'll give you a single number instead of a  matrix. You need to change the transpose operation so that it's done on `P1` not `P2` and `P2` will now simply be `P1`. Also you are overwriting the matrix `M` at each iteration.  I'm assuming you'd like to store these as individual slices in a 3D matrix.  To do this, allocate a 3D matrix where each 2D slice has an equal number of rows and columns which is the number of columns in `D` while the total number of slices is equal to the total number of rows in `D`.  Then just index into each slice and place the result accordingly:

```
M = zeros(size(D,2), size(D,2), size(D,1));
% Find matrices using matrix multiplication
for ii=1:size(D, 1)
    P = D(ii,:);
    M(:,:,ii) = P.'*P;
end
```

We get:

```
>> M

M(:,:,1) =

                5.18427361               -1.99137674
               -1.99137674                0.76492516


M(:,:,2) =

                  0.447561                 -0.315768
                 -0.315768                  0.222784


M(:,:,3) =

                  1.006009                 0.9215564
                 0.9215564                0.84419344


M(:,:,4) =

                6.81784321                1.34784982
                1.34784982                0.26646244
```

Depending on your taste, I would recommend using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to help you perform the same operation but perhaps doing it faster:

```
M = bsxfun(@times, permute(D, [2 3 1]), permute(D, [3 2 1]));
```

In fact, this solution is related to a similar question I asked in the past: [Efficiently compute a 3D matrix of outer products - MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab).  The only difference is that the question wanted to find the outer product of **columns** instead of the rows.

The way the code works is that we shift the dimensions with [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) of `D` so that we get two matrices of the sizes `2 x 1 x 4` and `1 x 2 x 4`.  By performing `bsxfun` and specifying the `times` function, this allows you to efficiently compute the matrix of outer products per slice simultaneously.