# How to vectorize the evaluation of outer product matrix for every row of the 2D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to speed the process in evaluation the outer product matrix. I have a 4*n matrix named `a`. I want to evaluate the outer product matrix for every row of `a`, by the formula:

```
K = a*a';
```

If I code this process using a `for` loop, it is as below:

```
K=zeros(4,4,size(a,2));
for i=1:size(a,2)
    K(:,:,i) = a(:,i)*a(:,i)';
end
```

I have found another method, using `cellfun`, which is even slower than before.

```
acell = num2cell(a, 1);
b = cellfun(@(x)(x*x'),acell,'UniformOutput',false);
K = reshape(cell2mat(b),4,4,[]);
```

Is there any good way to implement these process, such as vectorization?

Comment: Since R2016b, loops are not inherently slow - [source](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/). The `_fun` family of functions (`arrayfun`, `cellfun`, ...) are basically loops in disguise, in this case you've had to perform additional operations to work with `cellfun` so I'm not surprised it's slower. Your problem is optimising something which is already highly optimised in MATLAB (matrix multiplication). A loop is likely the quickest option, unless you only need specific elements and can do the individual multiplications in isolation

Comment: @Wolfie I try the method mentioned here and the answer that I duplicated. I just record the speed here. My Matlab version is 2019a. My 'a' matrix is 4*377644. The time of my own "for loop" is 0.4s; " obchardon's method is 0.036s; and the [answer]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab) using "bsxfun" is the fastest, 0.026s. As for the slowest "cellfun", it takes 7.3s. They really differ much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kron` to repeat the matrix n time, so no need to preallocation, then perform an element wise multiplication with `a(:).'`, finally reshape to add a 3rd dimension.

```
%Dummy 2D matrix 4x3
a = [1 4 7
     2 5 8
     3 6 9
     4 7 10]
%Size of the first dimension  
n = size(a,1);
%Repeat the matrix n time
p = kron(a,ones(1,n)).*a(:).'
%Reshape to A = 4x4x3
A = reshape(p,n,n,[])
```

You loose the readability of the for loop method but you should increase the performance.