# Is it possible to evaluate a'*B*a using bsxfun?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate the formula a'*B*a. My 'a' matrix size is n*4; and B is 4*4*n. The result is supposed to be n*1. If I code this process in for loop, it should be:

```
num = size(a,1);
result=zeros(num,1);
for i=1:num
    result(i)=a(i,:)*B(:,:,i)*a(i,:)';
end
```

Empirically,I found that using `bsxfun` should be faster. But I tried some times and failed to create the "singleton dimension". Is it possible to use it in this process? I am not familiar with the usage. I am very thankful for any suggestions and hints.

Comment: “Empirically,I found that using "bsxfun" should be faster.” Why do you say this? Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have test some codes. Much of them show that "bsxfun" is faster than the for loop. See my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786211/how-to-vectorize-the-evaluation-of-outer-product-matrix-for-every-row-of-the-2d) .I found a solution using "bsxfun" from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877835/efficiently-compute-a-3d-matrix-of-outer-products-matlab) Luis Mendo's answer. It is the fastest.

Comment: You can do something like in this question: https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/372841-sum-of-quadratic-forms-without-loops-and-fast but it probably won't save a lot of time because of the extra memory, and the fact that Matlab's JIT compilation is a lot better than it once was. The MTIMESX function might help, I haven't tried it though: https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support.

Comment: @ZhangWei note in you second link that the for loop was within 10% of the speed of the bsxfun.

Comment: In the last few days you've asked 3 similar (evolving) questions - is this part of some broader task which you're asking several parts of? There's nothing wrong with these questions as-is, just highlighting a trend...

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, you are right. I am exploring a broader task. I have made the code of broad task somehow, but it really ran slowly. I am revising the code for a faster speed. I asked the question to instantiate my problematic codes.  I think it is not good to throw out all the codes with bad readability. I am sorry to ask similar questions. But they are not simillar to me. Every time I solve a question, it helps me to revise several lines of code. All of my recent question is about the speed. Thank you for all the people helped me, including you.:)

Comment: @David 1. In my second link, one comment noted that Luis Mendo's bsxfun seems the fastest. 2. I am trying the mtimesx function, I will report the result ASAP. Thank you for your advise!

Comment: @David I have builded the mtimesx on my Matlab 2019a. I found the build-in function always match the speed. I thought Matlab had improved there functions well enough.